# How to fix "Failed to launch chrome!"

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to make a query to a website with puppeteer and I get error:

```
Error: Failed to launch chrome!
[0711/174138.253701:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

I've tried to give the followings arguments to

```
puppeteer.launch(args: ['--disable-setuid-sandbox'])
puppeteer.launch(args: ['--no-sandbox'])
```

But it doesn't work. It looks like a browser problem. I don't know what to do

My code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const url = "https://www.google.com.ar";

(async () => {
  try{
    const navegador = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']}); //Lanzo el chrome
    const pestaña = await navegador.newPage();//abro una nueva pestaña
    await pestaña.goto(url); //paso la url

    let tabla = await pestaña.evaluate(() => {

      const titulos = [
        ...document.querySelectorAll(".descrip_container")
      ].map((map_titulo) => map_titulo.innerText);
      //los "..." hace que en la pestaña se abra la consola
      const precios = [
        ...document.querySelectorAll(".atg_store_newPrice")
      ].map((map_precio) => map_precio.innerText);

      return productos.map((titulo, i) => ({titulos: titulo, precios: precios[i]}));
    })
    console.log(tabla);


    await navegador.close();

  }
  catch(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
})();
```

Comment: what do you mean by **it doesn't work**? What is the error with the 2 arguments?

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript syntax. Yevhen has a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to put `args` in the object:

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue also. Make sure you are updated to version 14 of nodejs. If it doesn't work from there install missing packages (see how to install them here: https://medium.com/@ssmak/how-to-fix-puppetteer-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libx11-xcb-so-1-c1918b75acc3). Along with adding the additional arguments (args) that Yevhen noted above.